# unable to find a matching controller Mvc Core

Tags: asp.net-core

When right click and click "Go to controller" or Ctrl + M  I get the below error 
and the other problem is that visual studio used to autocomplete action names and controller names inside helper tags, now it does not.

I couldn't find a way to fix it so I was hoping someone could help me

P.S The app is working, the problem is at the design time only

[image]

Comment: I'd like to confirm these information with you: 1) which version of visual studio you are using; 2) does same issue occur if you create a new controller and view.

Comment: Besides, this thread discussed similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473899/go-to-controller-shows-unable-to-find-a-matching-controller-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When right clicking 'go to controller' from the view, I get an error ('unable to find a matching controller')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61644076/when-right-clicking-go-to-controller-from-the-view-i-get-an-error-unable-to)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61644076/when-right-clicking-go-to-controller-from-the-view-i-get-an-error-unable-to

Comment: @Jess actually the other question is a duplicate of this one.

Comment: I don't really care except that the other question has an answer already.  Shrug?