# When right clicking 'go to controller' from the view, I get an error ('unable to find a matching controller')

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

When I right click on the `IActionResult Index()` method and click 'go to view', it takes me to the view.

But when I right-click inside the view, and click 'go to controller', it says 'unable to find a matching controller'; why does it only work in one direction in this instance?

Controller:

`/Controllers/Registration/RegistrationController.cs`

View:

`/Views/Registration/Index.cshtml`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely, because the naming and structure convention places all the controllers in the same folder and views for eachs controller in their own folder. So instead of this

> Controller:
>
> /Controllers/Registration/RegistrationController.cs
>
> View:
>
> /Views/Registration/Index.cshtml

Your folder structure should be like this:

> Controller:
>
> /Controllers/RegistrationController.cs
>
> View:
>
> /Views/Registration/Index.cshtml

Comment: This fixed the issue. So best practice for this would be to have all controllers in the same folder? Is there a way around this or would this entail creating specific 'solutions' (the way to link controller to view) to each directory of controllers?

Comment: Yes, this is the recommended way to do it. There is a way to create your own structure and define the folders you choose, but I'm sorry I can't remember how to do it. You don't normally have as many controllers as you have views, so the standard way works pretty well

Answer (score 0):

This is not a big deal.It happens because we use to create a view from a Action method present in the controller i.e., we first create an action method inside our controller then we go for creating its corresponding view.
You can simply go to the solution explorer and see the  views and there corresponding controllers.
This might be because one view can be related to one or more action methods with same names but all the multiple action methods having same name are related to only one view with that particular name.